# Can google-maps load different format data to generate a map on Android?

Tags: google-maps

I have used google-maps to create a gps app on Android. It was good. But right now. We don't want the map from google - maps. We want to load different formats data on our own hands to generate our own map. Can google - maps API do this job?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can let google maps load non-google data, but there are other libraries that can to that.

It depends a bit on what type of functionality you need, but you could try [mAppWidget](http://mapp.android-libraries.com/) (need to buy) or [osmdroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/) (open source).

My source is this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078479/what-android-3rd-party-libraries-are-there

Comment: functionality: customized GPS. I have done all features by using google- maps. Assumption changed. So... I want to see if i can save some work form existed app.